# router subscribe calls multiple time

Tags: angular

With this code

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    if (this.router.url.indexOf('page') > -1) {
      let id = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params['Id']
      this.busy = this.httpCall.get('/pub/page/GetPageById/' + id)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.pages = <Page[]>data
        })

      console.log(id)
    }
  })
}
```

when I navigate to `domain.com/#/en/page/13` it logs `13` as expected.

But when I navigate to the page which id is `27` it logs: `13 13 27`.

When I navigate back to `13` log has: `27 27 13`.

Why is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your logs you can see that your subscription is called three times on each route change. So that means events observable emits many signals but you interested in only one.

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.getData();
        this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(event =>  this.getData());    
  }
  getData(){
        if (this.router.url.indexOf('page') > -1) {
            let Id = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params['Id'];
            this.busy = this.httpCall.get('/pub/page/GetPageById/' + Id)
                     .subscribe(
                            data => {
                                this.pages = <Page[]>data;
                            });

             console.log(Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried that but now I'm getting empty page. It is not going inside that `if` statement

Comment: one more question. it works for that component but when I navigate to other from here I'm getting an error: `Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of null`

Comment: Did you still have that code from below answer?:
`ngOnDestroy() {
    this.myObserver.unsubscribe();
}` If so either remove it, either save subscription in proper variable.

Comment: You, sir. You're the man.

Answer (score 16):

You have to unsubscribe when you destroy your component.

First you have to

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core;'
```

Then you have to

```
export class myClass implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    myObserver = null;
    // Rest of your code
}
```

In your ngOnInit, you have to

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myObserver = this.router.events.subscribe(...);
}
```

Then, create a function

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.myObserver.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but result is the same..
P.S. ngOnDestroy needs ()

Comment: Thank you, didn't see, then if it still gives the same result, you should try moving the unsubscribe around, maybe in your subscribe so that once it's done, the observer unsubscribes directly !

Comment: and there comes my problems. I need subscribe for http call and I have it inside ngOnInit. If I want to redirect from page/13 to page/27 it is not doing that call..

Comment: even filter with navigationEnd criterial didn't help me, however this worked for me, thanks @trichetriche

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you write "this.router.events" on ngOnInit or Constructor, For fixing this issue you should write it on other function like that:

```
onRouteChange () {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (this.router.url.indexOf('page') > -1) {
            let Id = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params['Id'];
            this.busy = this.httpCall.get('/pub/page/GetPageById/' + Id)
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.pages = <Page[]>data;
                });

            console.log(Id);    
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

but there is another issue in this which you should consider when you use "this.router.events.subscribe", everything you wrote down in this function happens when you navigate in pages so it better to use this line to prevent run it on every path changes:

```
import {Router, NavigationStart} from '@angular/router';

onRouteChange () {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // this line
        if(event.url == 'your_page_path')
        if (this.router.url.indexOf('page') > -1) {
            let Id = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params['Id'];
            this.busy = this.httpCall.get('/pub/page/GetPageById/' + Id)
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.pages = <Page[]>data;
                });

            console.log(Id);    
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

`_routerSub = Subscription.EMPTY;`

Step 2:

```
ngOnInit(){

    this._routerSub = this.router.events
        .pipe(filter((event: RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.getPosts(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.cattmpd);
         });
}

ngOnDestroy(): {

    this._routerSub.unsubscribe()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem . I could able to resolve by maintaining a flag

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof 
        NavigationEnd).subscribe(() => {
        let render = false;
        if(this.router.url.indexOf('page') > -1 && !render){
        //here goes logic 
        render = true;
      }
    }
  }**
```